# How to implement long polling with Relay?

Tags: relayjs

Every 15 seconds, I need to refresh the data in all the fragments on one of my Relay containers. Is there a simple way to do this?

I have tried `relay.forceFetch({...})` but this error occurs:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: RelayStoreData.buildFragmentQueryForDataID(): Cannot refetch record `client:-8564613888_first(100)` without a path.
```

None of my variables are changing, and the documentation states that all the fragments will be refetched if `forceFetch` is handed an empty set.

I am not sure what the error warning means by "path" here.

Comment: This is a bug. If you have a moment, could you please log this as an issue on the Relay GitHub with as much detail as you can (a repro on the Relay Playground would be ideal). https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#/

Comment: Just logged it, thanks for the timely response!
https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/655

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed as of Relay v0.7.1
https://github.com/facebook/relay/commit/132605eef3ec93891ddb194952c7708ef6c5b605